# Django forms won't render (No reverse match)

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a form with Django 1.10 to create a comment on a Task object.
When I want to open the form, there is no field and when I try to submit, I got this error :

> NoReverseMatch at /tasks/29/comment/
>   Reverse for 'create_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'tasks/(?P[0-9]+)/comment/$']

How can I render my form on my template, and return to my "detail" view after submit ?

forms.py

```
class CreateCommentForm(forms.Form):
    commentary = forms.CharField(label='Commentary', widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentary = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=5000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.commentary
```

views.py

```
class CommentCreateView(SuperuserRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'tasks/create_comment_modal.html'
    form_class = CreateCommentForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = self.request.user
    task = Task.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    commentary = form.cleaned_data['commentary']
    comment = Comment(user=user, task=task, commentary=commentary)
    comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tasks:detail', kwargs={'pk': task.id}))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='create_comment'),
```

create_comment_modal.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form role="form" id="comment-create-form" name="comment-create-form" method="post" action="{% url 'tasks:create_comment' task.id %}">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add comment in task #{{ task.id }} - {{ task.title }}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.commentary.id_for_label }}">Commentary</label>
                {% render_field form.commentary class+="form-control" %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="current_user">
                Comment by : {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="deploy">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: try with:     def get_success_url(self):   return reverse('tasks:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.task.id}) in CommentCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{% url 'tasks:create_comment' task.id %}` inside your form looks suspicious.

Do you add `task` to your context in the `CommentCreateView`?

Add the following lines to your `CommentCreateView`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'task': Task.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])})
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly ! I used : context = super(CommentCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)